# Optimize performance of Scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website with the following structure:

- 1st Website is sitemap index, it contains 10-20 sitemap pages (sitemap_menu, but they change with some periodicity), each with 5k urls inside

I need to extract from each url an ID that I then use for an API request, which means that I have four scraping steps:

1. To get the sitemap_menus from sitemap_index
2. To get the urls from each sitemap_menu
3. To get IDs from each url
4. To get an API request using such ID

Currently, it is taking a lot of time executing. I have to scrape around 100K urls and it is doing 150 urls per minute (which is more than 11 hours). My code looks something like this:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    for sitemap_index in [sitemap_index]: # length 1
        yield scrapy.Request(sitemap_index)

def parse(self, response):

    sitemap_urls = response.xpath('//loc/text()').getall()
    sitemap_urls = [x for x in sitemap_urls if x.find('sitemap_menu') > 0]
        if sitemap_urls is not None:
            yield from response.follow_all(sitemap_urls, callback=self.parse_urls, headers=self.headers)

def parse_urls(self, response):
    rest_urls = response.xpath('//url/text()').getall()
    shuffle(rest_urls)
    yield from response.follow_all(rest_urls, callback=self.parse_enrichment, 
                                   headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={'is_api': False)

def parse_enrichment(self, response, country_id, is_api):
    # Function to perform enrichment of restaurants
    # 1. Getting and parsing HTML to get JSON containing restaurant ID
    # 2. API Request to get extra information using the id

    if not is_api:
        html_json = response.xpath('//*[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()').get()
        # Load JSON found in HTML into a dict to get the id
        if html_json is not None:
            indiv_json = json.loads(html_json.replace('\\n', ' ').replace('\\r', ' '))
            try:
                indiv_id = indiv_json['id']
            except KeyError:
                self.logger.debug('__NEXT_DATA__ not found')
                raise KeyError

            # 2nd enrichment request: Request JSON from API
            indiv_api_url = self.country_mapping['api_url'].format(indiv_id). # some dict with the API url

            yield response.follow(indiv_api_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_enrichment,
                                  cb_kwargs={'is_api': True})

    else:
        indiv = json.loads(response.text.replace('\\n', ' ').replace('\\r', ' '))
        try:
            indiv = indiv['somekey']
        except KeyError:
            self.logger.debug('API response structure different than what was expected')
            raise KeyError
        indiv['url'] = response.url
        self.indiv_details[indiv['id']] = indiv

        yield store
```

What can I do to increase substantially its speed? Is it related to code design? Settings? I have thought on creating two spiders, one for fetching all the urls and the other one to get the id and then do the API request, but I don't really want to have two separate spiders for this. I have set up CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN, CONCURRENT_ITEMS to different values (50, 80, 100, 200, 250), but there is no performance increase.

EDIT: I have also implemented this using the SitemapSpider class and the speed is very similar (170 urls per min). I had run something similar using multithreading and requests library and the speed I was seeing was of 350 urls per minute

Comment: where does the `sitemap_urls` variable come from in your list comprehension in the `parse` method?

Comment: @Alexander from a xpath selector. I just added that to the question